# Issues with multiple variables in the same file name

Tags: batch-file

I'm having an issue with multiple variables in the same line in a batch script. The line in question is:

```
echo copy "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMBackupTempFile.txt" "%%dblogfolder%%BACKUP_RCMDB_%%tdstamp%%.txt" >> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
```

When I run the install batch script to create all the main script, the output that is written to the batch file is

```
copy "%dbtempfolder%RCMDBCheckTempFile.txt" "%dblogfolder%CHECK_RCMDB_%tdstamp%.txt"
```

When the actual script executes, it should put the output in **C:\My Commpany\DBLogs\Check_RCMDB_07082021162248.txt**. The problem is that it drops the file in the same folder as the script was executed from.

Full code:

```
@echo on
    rem Set the company name
    set companyname=My Company

    rem Choose the name of the DB to be backed up
    set dbname=RCMDB

    rem Choose the login for the database
    set dblogin=Login\Login

    rem The db backup file name followed by the date/time of the DB backup. (the date is automatically added. DO NOT ADD THE DATE BELOW! 
    rem Example: RCMDBBackup-20210706-000000.bak
    set dbfilename=RCMDBBackup-

    rem Delete backups older than X days
    set dbbackuphistory=90

    rem Choose primary backup location for DB backups
    set primarydbbackuploc=C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.RCM\MSSQL\Backup\

    rem Choose which days of the week to backup the DB. ex: MON
    rem For multiple days use commas without spaces EX: SUN,WED
    set backupdays=SUN,WED

    rem Choose the time you want to backup. Time MUST be in 24hr format. EX: 00:00 for midnight EX: 23:57 for 11:57PM
    set backuptime=00:00

    rem Create main folder
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\" (
            mkdir "C:\%companyname%\"
    )

    rem Create scipts folder
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\Scripts" (
            mkdir "C:\%companyname%\Scripts"
    )

    rem Create Tasks folder
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\Tasks" (
            mkdir "C:\%companyname%\Tasks"
    )

    rem Create temp folder
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\Temp\" (
            mkdir "C:\%companyname%\Temp\"
    )

    rem Create DB Logs folder
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\DBLogs\" (
            mkdir "C:\%companyname%\DBLogs\"
    )

        if not exist "X:\%companyname%\DBLogs\" (
            mkdir "X:\%companyname%\DBLogs\"
    )

    rem Create DB Backups folder
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\DBBackups\" (
            mkdir "C:\%companyname%\DBBackups\"
    )

        if not exist "X:\%companyname%\DBBackups\" (
            mkdir "X:\%companyname%\DBBackups\"
    )

    rem Create SQL script to check the RCM DB for corruption
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\Scripts\Check RCM DB.sql" (
            echo DBCC CHECKDB>> "C:\%companyname%\Scripts\Check RCM DB.sql"
    )

    rem Create SQL script to Backup the RCM db
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\Scripts\Backup RCM DB.sql" (
        (
            echo DECLARE @MyFileName varchar(1000^)
            echo SELECT @MyFileName = (SELECT '%primarydbbackuploc%%dbfilename%' + convert(varchar(500^),GetDate(^),112^) + '.bak'^)
            echo BACKUP DATABASE [%DBNAME%] TO  DISK = @MyFileName WITH checksum, NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'RCMDB-Full Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
            echo GO
        ) 1>"C:\%companyname%\Scripts\Backup RCM DB.sql"
    )

    rem create bat script to check and backup the RCM DB
        if not exist "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat" (
            echo @echo off >> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo set dbscriptfolder=C:\%companyname%\Scripts\>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo set dbtempfolder=C:\%companyname%\Temp\>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo set dblogfolder=C:\%companyname%\DBLogs\>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo set rdblogfolder=X:\%companyname%\DBLogs\>> "X:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo set dbtaskfolder=C:\%companyname%\Tasks\>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo set tdstamp=%%date:~4,2%%%%date:~7,2%%%%date:~10,4%%%%time:~0,2%%%%time:~3,2%%%%time:~6,2%%>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo.>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo ^mode ^con: ^cols=55 ^lines=5 ^&^& ^color 4f ^&^& title RCM DB CHECK IN PROGRESS....>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo echo *****CHECKING RCM DATABASE*****>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo sqlcmd -S %dblogin% -d %DBNAME% -i "%%dbscriptfolder%%Check RCM DB.sql" -o "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMDBCheckTempFile.txt">> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo copy "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMDBCheckTempFile.txt" "%%dblogfolder%%CHECK_RCMDB_%%tdstamp%%.txt">> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo copy "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMDBCheckTempFile.txt" "%%rdblogfolder%%CHECK_RCMDB_%%tdstamp%%.txt">> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo PING localhost -n 3 ^>NUL>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo del "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMDBCheckTempFile.txt">> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo.>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo.>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo ^mode ^con: ^cols=55 lines=5 ^&^& ^color 4f ^&^& ^title RCM BACKUP IN PROGRESS....>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo echo *****BACKING UP RCM DATABASE*****>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo sqlcmd -S %dblogin% -d %DBNAME% -i "%%dbscriptfolder%%Backup RCM DB.sql" -o "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMBackupTempFile.txt">> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo copy "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMBackupTempFile.txt" "%%dblogfolder%%BACKUP_RCMDB_%%tdstamp%%.txt" >> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo copy "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMBackupTempFile.txt" "%%rdblogfolder%%BACKUP_RCMDB_%%tdstamp%%.txt" >> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo PING localhost -n 3 ^>^NUL>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo del "%%dbtempfolder%%RCMBackupTempFile.txt">> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo.>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            echo.>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            rem Transfer DB backups to additional drive.
            set currentdate=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
            xcopy /y /s /d:%CURRENTDATE% "%primarydbbackuploc%" "X:\%companyname%\DBBACKUPS"
            rem echo.>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
            rem Delete DB backups older than X days
            rem echo ForFiles /p "%primarydbbackuploc%" /s /d -%dbbackuphistory% /c "cmd /c del @file">> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"
    )
    rem Create scheduled task to backup RCM DB and transfer backups to external drive
        SCHTASKS /CREATE /SC WEEKLY /D %backupdays% /TN "RCM DB BACKUP" /TR "C:\%companyname%\tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat" /ST %backuptime%
```

Comment: I don't see what you are having a problem with.  The file looks to be named correctly based on the usage of the date and time variables.  You have not explained what your expected output should be.

Comment: @Squashman The output should be `copy "%dbtempfolder%RCMDBCheckTempFile.txt" "(%dblogfolder%)(CHECK_RCMDB_)(%tdstamp%).txt"` So it should copy the tempfile to `C:\My Company\DBLogs\Check_RCMDB_07082021162248.txt` but if is putting the file in the root of where my script is (forgot to mention this) as opposed to the specified location, with its respective name.

Comment: @Squashman Evidently I didn't even understand the true nature of what my problem was. Along with my previous comment, I updated the post with ACCURATE information...

Comment: I'm going to assume that you're having issues with lines `95` and `104`, not lines `94` and `103` as shown in your question. The reason I say that is that from my quick scan over your content I would have expected line `87` to read as `echo set rdblogfolder=X:\%companyname%\DBLogs\>> "C:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"`, not `echo set rdblogfolder=X:\%companyname%\DBLogs\>> "X:\%companyname%\Tasks\RCM-DB-BACKUP.bat"`